# How to Log Client IP Address when there is a Proxy Server between the Client and IIS server?

Tags: iis-7, proxy, reverse-proxy

I hosted a sample ASP page in IIS server IP: 10.1.1.102 and forward proxy server ip as 10.1.1.106, when i try try to access the page through proxy from any other machine(eg:192.168.31.100), in IIS advanced logs i'm getting proxy machine IP (10.1.1.106)  instead of real client IP(192.168.31.100)

Comment: It should be possible, what proxy are you using?

Comment: httpd as proxy server

Comment: Which version of IIS are you running?  I ask because IIS can use the `X-Forwarded-For` header which contains the proxied/client address, _i.e._ requesting client's IP address, and which Apache `mod_proxy` _should_ be sending, but the exact instructions for doing so depend on the IIS version.